# Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<Integer,Item> to HashMap<Integer,Item>

Tags: java, jsp, generics, hashmap, type-mismatch

I am trying to use this piece of code in my JSP to loop over a Hashmap. When the jsp loads

```
    HashMap<Integer, Item> itemsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
    itemsMap = customer1.getItems();
      for(Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry:itemsMap.entrySet()){
              Integer k=entry.getKey();
             Item item=entry.getValue();
      }
```

Here is the error that is displayed when I try to load the jsp

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
    An error occurred at line: 159 in the jsp file: /JSP/cart.jsp
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<Integer,Item> to HashMap<Integer,Item>
    156: //   HashMap itemsMap = customer1.getItems();
    157: //          for(Iterator i = itemsMap.keySet().iterator();i.hasNext();){
    158:      HashMap<Integer, Item> itemsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
    159:      itemsMap = customer1.getItems();
    160:           for(Map.Entry<Integer, Item> entry:itemsMap.entrySet()){
    161:                   Integer k=entry.getKey();
    162:                   Item item=entry.getValue();
```

The same code worked fine when I used it in a servlet for the same purpose.
Can someone tell what is that I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

These are the related classes:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    // private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private HashMap<Integer,Item> items=new HashMap<Integer,Item>();
    public Customer() {

    }
    public HashMap<Integer,Item> getItems(){ return items;}
}

public static class Item {
    private String name;
    private String skew;
    private String amount;
    public Item(String name, String skew, String amount) {
        this.name=name; this.skew=skew; this.amount=amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ensure your `Item` class is imported into the JSP and that it is the correct `Item` class.

Comment: What customer1.getitems signature can you please update on ur post

Comment: @gatisahu Here is some relevant information on the related classes
`public class Customer
{
  private String name;
  private String address;
//  private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
  private HashMap<Integer,Item> items=new HashMap<Integer,Item>();
  public Customer(){ }
  public HashMap<Integer,Item> getItems(){
    return items;}
}`

`public class Item
{
  private String name;
  private String skew;
  private String amount;

  public Item(String name, String skew, String amount){
    this.name=name;
    this.skew=skew;
    this.amount=amount;
  }}`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the app server you're using you can check the Java file that was generated from the JSP file. In Tomcat for instance it's somewhere in the 'work' directory tree. Some IDEs can also open it for you when you right-click the JSP file in a debugger session and click something like "Show Servlet" in the context menu. Please be aware that this has no chance of working when you're outside a debugger session.

Once you got this file open you can check the imports and everything else and why it won't compile.

The comment by user Zircon regarding the type "Item" and whether it's one of the imports in the JSP is probably correct. I'm not worried about the missing import though but about the design of your application. It's a very strong convention in web development to separate business logic and display logic.
In other words: There is no circumstance in which you should have Java code in your JSP. All business logic (that's what your Java code should be about) should be encapsulated in controllers and models, or, if you want, in beans that you instantiate from within your JSPs. If you want to iterate over something then use `<c:forEach >` and similar provisions.

If you do insist to use Java inside the JSP, then at least use the diamond operator: `HashMap<Integer, Item> itemsMap = new HashMap<>();`

That way the problem would presumably create a more enlightening compiler or runtime message.

If all this doesn't help, then please really find the servlet file (.java file) the app server created from your JSP and copy the import section to your question so we know which type of Item it's trying to access.

Comment: Container converts jsp page into java servlet (pageName_jsp.java)  you can check that file directly 

For Ex. here is the path for the converted java file.

**apache-tomcat-7.0.68_eclipse/work/Catalina/localhost/<ApplicationName>/org/apache/jsp/WEB_XXX/pages**